# python os rename a file name match with certain name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file name INVENTORY_202005031549.csv in a certain folder C:\users\me\desktop\rpa

The file name after the underscore **_** contains the **yyyymmddhhmm** format.

How do i use os.rename it for such pattern file name from Inventory_* to Inventory.csv

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the existing file name using `os.path.splitext` method. Split the string using pattern _ and rename it using `os.rename`. I hope it will work for you -

```
fileName = os.path.splitext("C:/users/me/desktop/rpa/INVENTORY_202005031549.csv")[0];
newFileName = fileName.split("_")[0]
os.rename('C:/users/me/desktop/rpa/INVENTORY_202005031549.csv','C:/users/me/desktop/rpa/'+newFileName.capitalize()+'.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks , but the file name is not fixed  INVENTORY_202005031549.csv , the text after _ change accordingly to the date/hhmm when i download it.